# is there any way to do scalar indexing in perl?

Tags: perl, indexing, bitwise-operators

i have a scalar with 32bit hex value
eg:

```
$foo_value = 0xabcdf123
```

I have 4 other scalars, `$pho0 $pho1 $pho2 $pho3` such that

```
$pho0 = $foo_value [7:0]  ## lower 8 bits of $foo_value [0x23]
$pho1 = $foo_value [15:8] ## bits 15-8 of $foo_value [0xf1]
$pho2 = $foo_value [23:16] ##0xcd
$pho3 = $foo_value[31:24]  ## 0xab
```

Is there a way I can do this in perl? Note, `$foo_value` cannot be called an array so can't do array indexing. Is there anything called scalar indexing?

Comment: You could write a sub that takes a hex string and breaks it into an array of values. You could write a class that allows byte-wise access using array-like syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Is that different from using bit-wise operators?

```
$pho0 = $foo_value & 0xFF;
$pho1 = ($foo_value >> 8) & 0xFF;
$pho2 = ($foo_value >> 16) & 0xFF;
$pho3 = ($foo_value >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

A subroutine that takes a hex string (yea, like the comment).

This way you don't have to bother with naming each separate variable (eg. $foo1, $foo2, $foo3)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $hval = "0xabcdf123";   #test value
my @bar = splByte($hval);

sub splByte{
    my $foo = shift;
    my @temp = split('',$foo);
    my @bar;

    for my $i(0 .. @temp){
        if ($i < (@temp-1)){
            my $string = "0x" . join('',@temp[$i, ($i+1)]);
            push(@bar, $string) unless $i%2;
        }
    }
    shift @bar;

    return @bar;
}
```

Comment: After rereading the question a few times, I realize this may not be what you are looking for.